# Wordpress wpdp->getResults does not execute my sql when SQL string has '%f"

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Here is my code when executing a query. I show the SQL query before execute and the last was executed.

```
public static function getProductByUser($user_id, $page, $containName, $sort, $filterOptions)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $limit = 40;
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $querySort = self::buildSortQuery($sort);
    $pidi_db = new DatabaseApi();
    $filterQuery = "";
    if ($filterOptions) {
        $filterQuery = self::buildFilterQuery($filterOptions);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT hp.*, CASE WHEN pf.product_id IS NULL THEN false ELSE true  END as favorite
    FROM {$pidi_db->{UserDomain::$table_name}} ud JOIN {$pidi_db->{self::$table_name}} hp ON ud.domain_name = hp.domain
    LEFT JOIN {$pidi_db->{HotProductFavorite::$table_name}} pf ON pf.product_id = hp.product_id 
    WHERE ud.user_id = %d AND hp.title LIKE %s" . $filterQuery . " GROUP BY hp.product_id " . $querySort . " LIMIT %d OFFSET %d ";


    $query = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $user_id, "%" . $containName . "%", $limit, $offset);

     print_r($sql);
     print_r("\n");

     $wpdb->get_results($query);
     print_r($wpdb->last_query);
     die;

}
```

When final sql string return like that. The query was executed:

```
=== Sql after prepare ====
SELECT hp.*, CASE WHEN pf.product_id IS NULL THEN false ELSE true  END as favorite
    FROM wp_pidi_user_domain ud JOIN wp_pidi_hot_product_tracking hp ON ud.domain_name = hp.domain
    LEFT JOIN wp_pidi_hot_product_favorite pf ON pf.product_id = hp.product_id 
    WHERE ud.user_id = %d AND hp.title LIKE %s AND hp.domain LIKE '%asadas%' GROUP BY hp.product_id ORDER BY hp.published_at DESC LIMIT %d OFFSET %d 
 === SQL was executed ===
SELECT hp.*, CASE WHEN pf.product_id IS NULL THEN false ELSE true  END as favorite
    FROM wp_pidi_user_domain ud JOIN wp_pidi_hot_product_tracking hp ON ud.domain_name = hp.domain
    LEFT JOIN wp_pidi_hot_product_favorite pf ON pf.product_id = hp.product_id 
    WHERE ud.user_id = 1 AND hp.title LIKE '%%' AND hp.domain LIKE '%asadas%' GROUP BY hp.product_id ORDER BY hp.published_at DESC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0
```

Seem like wpdp executed my query. But when final SQL string return like this, wpdp did not execute my query and do not show any error in log file. I think to prevent injection function has rejected my query.

```
=== sql after prepare ===
SELECT hp.*, CASE WHEN pf.product_id IS NULL THEN false ELSE true  END as favorite
    FROM wp_pidi_user_domain ud JOIN wp_pidi_hot_product_tracking hp ON ud.domain_name = hp.domain
    LEFT JOIN wp_pidi_hot_product_favorite pf ON pf.product_id = hp.product_id 
    WHERE ud.user_id = %d AND hp.title LIKE %s AND hp.title LIKE '%fairy%' GROUP BY hp.product_id ORDER BY hp.published_at DESC LIMIT %d OFFSET %d 
=== lastest sql was executed ===
SELECT * FROM wp_pidi_filter_options WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `screen_id`=1
```

It's a previous sql executed not the sql after prepare .

Can someone help me? Thank!

Comment: The reason here is wpdb does not accept string '%f....', i think . Can someone have other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: 
buildFilterQuery() function will always return string like that, improving my answer if you have better solution !:

```
"AND hp.title LIKE '¥REGEX¥Fairy¥REGEX¥' "
```

And after prepare: `$query = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$arg);` i replace REGEX place holder:

```
   $newFilterQuery = str_replace(self::$REGEX, '%', $query);
   return $wpdb->get_results($newFilterQuery);
```